# Java9 Module - Maven: ServiceLoader.load( HelloInterface.class) cannot find Interface class

Tags: java, maven, java-9, java-module

In IntelliJ/Maven I want to work with Java9 / modules and the ServiceLoader. I built a simple 2 module project. Using maven the ServiceLoader.load( ...) cannot find the implementation of the HelloInterface.class. **Why?**

I created the project via IntelliJ by first adding the 2 modules. Rebuilding the project works fine. Clean/installing via Maven also works fine - well, the unit test fails ;-(

**UPDATE 1**: Running with IntelliJ is OK due to putting the module-info.java right under the sources root. I compile using the "**Rebuild project**".

**How can I use this 2 module project with the ServiceLoader with Maven?**

My simple project struture is:

[image]

pom.xml:

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>14</source>
        <target>14</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>java9.com.hello</module>
    <module>java9.com.hello.client</module>
</modules>
```

File: module java9.com.hello / src / main / java / module-info.jar

```
module java9.com.hello {
    exports com.hello;
    exports com.hello.services;
    provides com.hello.services.HelloInterface with com.hello.services.HelloWorldIntefaceImpl;
}
```

File: module java9.com.hello / com.hello.services.HelloInterface.java

```
public interface HelloInterface {
    String sayHello();
}
```

File: module java9.com.hello / com.hello.services.HelloWorldIntefaceImpl.java

```
public class HelloWorldIntefaceImpl implements HelloInterface {
    public String sayHello() {
        String helloString = "Hello world by Inteface!";
        System.out.println( helloString);
        return helloString;
    }
}
```

File: module java9.com.hello / pom.xml (without the boilerplate)

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>jdk-new-features</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>java9.com.hello</artifactId>
```

File: module java9.com.hello.client / src / main / java / module-info.jar.
This file is giving the compiler error.

```
module java9.com.hello.client {
    requires java9.com.hello; // <==== gives the ERROR
    uses com.hello.services.HelloInterface;
}
```

File: module java9.com.hello.client / com.hello.client.HelloWorldClient.java

```
public class HelloWorldClient {
    public static void main (String arg[]) {
        HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();
        System.out.println(hello.sayHelloWorld());
        Iterable<HelloInterface> services = ServiceLoader.load(HelloInterface.class);
        HelloInterface service = services.iterator().next();
        service.sayHello();
    }
    public String callService() {
        Iterable<HelloInterface> services = ServiceLoader.load(HelloInterface.class);
        HelloInterface service = services.iterator().next();
        return service.sayHello();
    }
}
```

The pom.xml is: module java9.com.hello.client / pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>java9.com.hello</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Unit test file: module java9.com.hello.client / com.hello.client.HelloWorldClientTest.java

```
public class HelloWorldClientTest {
    @Test
    public void testModuleInterfaceImplementation() {
        HelloWorldClient helloWorldClient = new HelloWorldClient();
        assertEquals( "Hello world by Inteface!", helloWorldClient.callService());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the pom file of the `java9.com.hello` module. Furthermore if you really like to use modules your `module-info.java` has to be located into `src/main/java` and to use a service loader you have to define `META-INF/services/...` files which looks like you don't have  done yet.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I added the trivial pom.xml. I will work on your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you need the META-INF/services files when you have modules and a provides directive. On the other hand you do need to export com.hello.services (you only export com.hello). Plus you need to run with modules enabled or the provides statement won't help.

Comment: „*…the compiler error…*“ — Please edit your question to include the details of „*the compiler error*“? TIA.

Comment: See the title of the question and the first paragraph.